# Laravel 4 PHP: Routes Order Issue

Tags: php, laravel-4

EDIT:
I am using Laravel 4 PHP and initially I thought this problem was related to the 'link_to_route' method on a webpage so you can simply link to another webpage that does not contain any dynamic data.

However, I am discovering that the order you list your Routes will ultimately determine if your routes are successfully reached or not.

**Authors2.php (Controller)**

```
class Authors2_Controller extends BaseController {

public $restful = true;

public function contact() {

    return View::make('authors2.index')
    ->with('title','Authors and Books')
    ->with('authors2', Author2::orderBy('name')->get());
}

public function getnew() {

    return View::make('authors2.new')
        ->with('title', 'Add New Author');
}
```

**Routes.php**

```
Route::get('authors2', array('as'=>'authors2', 'uses' =>'Authors2_Controller@contact'));

Route::get('authors2/new', array('as'=>'new_author', 'uses'=>'Authors2_Controller@getnew'));
```

**index.blade.php (view)**

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')
<h1>Authors2 Home Page </h1>

<ul>
@foreach($authors2 as $author2)
    <li>{{ link_to_route('author2', $author2->name, $parameters = array($author2->id)) }}</li>
@endforeach 
</ul>

<p>{{ link_to_route('new_author', 'Add Author') }} </p>

@endsection
```

When I click on the 'Add Author' link, I get the error 'Trying to get property of non-object' error.

**EDIT:**
So now when I change the order of the routing where if I list the 'authors2/new' route BEFORE the 'authors2' route, the route will actually work:

```
Route::get('authors2/new', array('as'=>'new_author', 'uses'=>'Authors2_Controller@getnew'));
Route::get('authors2', array('as'=>'authors2', 'uses' =>'Authors2_Controller@contact'));
```

Does this have to deal with how Routes are first received and if so, why does this happen?

Comment: Laravel will return the first route that matches. That's why you should order your routes from the most to the least specific. authors2 is also matched in authors2/new. But because authors2/new is more specific than authors2 it will not match authors2.

Comment: Thanks @Barry_127 - That makes sense to me now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Barry_127, Laravel will match routes based from most specific to least specific.  So its good practice to list your routes in that order.